# Solar array and inverter troubles

Tags: solar-panels

I have a solar array on my rv and have installed a power bright 6000-12 inverter which I wired the rv supply line directly into the lugs on the front panel. I am having a problem with the inverter faulting. I checked the four receptacles on the inverter and they all show as n open ground the inverter has a chassis ground wire installed and the each sets of cables are connected to three 12 volt 180 amp/hour batteries wired in parallel and a solar panel with 30 amp charge controler.  There are two of these panel/battery setups one on each pair of cables. The inverter turns on and faults after about a minute disconnecting the 120 ac power. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue? I am gong to add chassis grounds to that battery banks in the meantime while waiting for some replies.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of the way things are wired up? And when you say the inverter faults, does it tell you what the fault is?

Answer (score 1):

In [the manual](https://invertersrus.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PW6000-12-MANUAL.pdf) they discuss "battery bank" *singular*.   As in one battery bank.

From a Home Depot review:

> Installation tip: This unit has 4 battery terminals and all four terminals should have a dedicated minimum zero gauge cable and all 4 cables must connect to the same battery even if multiple batteries are present.

So this means that the 2 + terminals and 2 - terminals are not intended to support dual battery banks. They are intended to **parallel** the DC wiring side, due to the very large startup current needed (1000A when starting a large load).